# Right join in zend2 not working

Tags: mysql, join, zend-framework, zend-framework2, right-join

I have a query that returns the attributes of the employee and its objectives, what I want is to return all the employees regardless if he's objectives are already set or not. This is my query

```
 $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($options) {
        $select->columns(array('*',
            new Expression("(SELECT CONCAT(employee.first_name, ' ', employee.last_name)
                             FROM employee
                             WHERE id = CAST(os_form.created_by AS CHAR)) as created_by"),
            new Expression("SUM(CASE WHEN os_form_objective.type = 1 THEN objective.result * objective.weight / 100 END) * os_event.business_weight / 100 as business_result"),
            new Expression("SUM(CASE WHEN os_form_objective.type = 2 THEN objective.result * objective.weight / 100 END) * os_event.team_weight / 100 as team_result"),
            new Expression("SUM(CASE WHEN os_form_objective.type = 3 THEN objective.result * objective.weight / 100 END) * os_event.individual_weight / 100 as individual_result"),
        ));
        $select->join('os_event',
                      'os_form.os_event_id = os_event.id',
                      array('business_weight', 'team_weight', 'individual_weight'))
               ->join('business_line',
                      'os_form.business_line_id = business_line.id',
                      array('business_line' => 'name'))
               ->join('unit',
                      'os_form.unit_id = unit.id',
                      array('unit' => 'name'))
               ->join('sub_unit',
                      'os_form.sub_unit_id = sub_unit.id',
                      array('sub_unit' => 'name'))
               ->join('employee',
                      'os_form.employee_id = employee.id',
                      array('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'date_started', 'role'),
                      Select::JOIN_RIGHT)

               ->join('os_form_objective',
                      'os_form.os_event_id = os_form_objective.os_event_id AND os_form.employee_id = os_form_objective.employee_id AND os_form.sub_unit_id = os_form_objective.sub_unit_id AND os_form.role = os_form_objective.role',
                      array())
               ->join('objective',
                      'os_form_objective.objective_id = objective.id',
                      array());
        $select->group(array('os_form.os_event_id', 'os_form.employee_id', 'os_form.sub_unit_id'));

        if (!empty($options)) {

            $select->where($options);
            //$select->Where("employee.first_name LIKE ?", '%'.$name.'%');
        }
     // \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($select);
    });
    return $resultSet;
```

as per my query I tried to right join the employee table so that the query will return all the employees but when I tried to run it, only those who have objectives set are returned.

PS. Objectives are in os_form table.
Thanks.

Comment: you could maybe use joinLeft or joinRight instead of join ?

Comment: Hi tried that but unfortunately doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: why doesn't it work ? show us what you've tried. What is the final request you want to be build (as a string) ?